# Delphi Indy HTTP.GET high cpu usage

Tags: delphi, indy

on first download there is high cpu usage, later all is ok. This problem exists since Delphi XE7 and now in XE8. In earlier versions i think there was always low CPU usage. I tested it with latest SSL files from https://indy.fulgan.com/

Thanks for help.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  dane: TMemoryStream;

begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
  IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
  IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json';
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
  IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Client-ID', 'smb61nyd0vxmqdn9d3k735qbx41cdyg');
  dane := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=StarCraft:%20Brood%20War', dane);
  finally
    dane.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));` is redundant as the folder of the calling process is the first place the OS looks when loading DLLs.  Also FYI, you don't need to create the `SSLIOHandler` manually anymore when accessing an HTTPS url unless you have to customize its settings: [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx).

Comment: I removed it now, thanks. Any suggestion about CPU? Is this normal?

Comment: No.  However, unless you are developing for mobile, your code is leaking the `TIdHTTP` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` objects, so that may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: I see no async code here, have you tried to put this code inside a separate thread? What is the size of your data you're fetching?